# Matlab Ode23 C++ file

Tags: matlab, ode

I want to know can i use this code for my projects?
ftp://ftp.nodc.noaa.gov/nodc/archive/arc0032/0071189/1.1/data/0-data/AT003L11/RR_MOVED/FUNFUN/ODE23.C

it uses a include mex.h file in the beginning. what is that? what is that mex header doing there? can i just ignore that line and use the rest of the code in somewhere else?
I want to use the file in android NDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is meant to be compiled for Matlab to process. If you have Matlab installed you can compile it from the console. If not you will not be able to compile this by simply removing the include statement. Your best bet is to read through the code, understand what it is doing, and use it as an example for your own code.

Comment: tnx. do you have any library (C/C++) for solving ODE?

Comment: @Shahryar I haven't used one personally, but I typed "C++ ODE" into google and the first link is an open source C++ header library: http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/